# Based on user input in flask form sending Pandas Grouped data to flask template

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask, data-science, flask-wtforms

Here is my challenge:
1.I have the below form in flask using jinja:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNRul.png)

2.Based on the user input of start date,end date and site,i need the following output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg2Xl.png)

3.I have read the excel and parse using pandas:

Input Excel Data:
[inputdata.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k4QzpbJQTi1dHBA5oMfyuDDS1vHEJjx3GWpw7bfLS0k/edit?usp=sharing)

4.In flask I have created the following:

````
    ```
    class hofails(object):
        def __init__(self,startdate,enddate,site):
            self.start_date = startdate
            self.end_date = enddate
            self.site = site
            self.results = []
            self.data = self.loadData()
            self.df = self.loadData()
            self.data['Site'] = copy.deepcopy(self.data['CELL'].str[1:9])
            self.data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

        def loadData(self):
            import pandas as pd
            excel_file = 'LTE_HO_T.xlsx'
            df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
            df = df[['PERIOD_START_TIME','SITE', 'CELL', 'NEIGHBOR_CELL', 'Inter eNB HO Execution 
                 Attempts',\
                'Inter eNB HO Execution Failure Rate', 'Inter eNB HO Execution Successes',\
                'Early Handover Type1', 'Early Handover Type2', 'Late Handovers']]

            return df        

        def get_data_by_site(self, site_id):
            return self.df[self.df['SITE'] == site_id]

        def get_data_cell(self, cell_data, start_date, end_date):
            cell_data = cell_data[(cell_data['PERIOD_START_TIME'] >= start_date) & 
            (cell_data['PERIOD_START_TIME'] <= end_date)].dropna(axis=1)

            cell_data = cell_data[['PERIOD_START_TIME', 'SITE', 'CELL', 'NEIGHBOR_CELL', 'Inter eNB 
                        HO Execution Attempts', \
                       'Inter eNB HO Execution Failure Rate', 'Inter eNB HO Execution Successes', \
                       'Early Handover Type1', 'Early Handover Type2', 'Late Handovers']]

            cell_data = cell_data.groupby(['CELL', 'NEIGHBOR_CELL'], as_index=False)['Inter eNB HO 
                        Execution Attempts', \
                                                               'Inter eNB HO Execution Failure Rate', 
                       'Inter eNB HO Execution Successes', \
                                                               'Early Handover Type1', 'Early 
                      Handover Type2', 'Late Handovers'].mean()

             cell_data = cell_data[cell_data['Inter eNB HO Execution Failure Rate'] > 0.02]

             cell_data['Avg. Inter eNB HO Execution Fails'] = cell_data['Inter eNB HO Execution 
             Attempts'] - cell_data['Inter eNB HO Execution Successes']

             cell_data = cell_data[['CELL', 'NEIGHBOR_CELL', 'Inter eNB HO Execution Attempts', 
                        'Inter eNB HO Execution Successes',
                        'Avg. Inter eNB HO Execution Fails', 'Inter eNB HO Execution Failure Rate', 
                        'Early Handover Type1','Early Handover Type2', 'Late Handovers']]        
             return cell_data
    ```
````

5.Then in the 'main.py' i have used the following codes:

````
    ```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='devkey'
    class HO_FAILS(FlaskForm):  # Define the form fields and validation parameters
        StartDate = DateField('DatePicker', format="%Y-%m-%d")
        EndDate = DateField('DatePicker', format="%Y-%m-%d")
        site = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])

    @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def lte_ho_fails():
        form = HO_FAILS()
        final_result = {}
        from hofails import hofails
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            StartDate = form.StartDate.data
            EndDate = form.EndDate.data
            site = form.site.data

        StartDate = StartDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        EndDate = EndDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        hof = hofails(StartDate,EndDate,site)
        site_data = hof.get_data_by_site(site)   
        for cell in site_data["CELL"]:
            cell_data = site_data[site_data["CELL"] == cell]
            cell_data_avg = hof.get_data_cell(cell_data, StartDate, EndDate)
            if cell_data_avg.isna().all(): continue
            data_list = []
            davg = dict(cell_data_avg)
            data_list.append(davg)
            final_result[cell] = data_list

        return render_template('lte_ho.html', form=form,
                                            title='LTE HO Fail Analysis',
                                            result=final_result,)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
````

6.I have created the template as follows:

````
    ```
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype=multipart/form-data class="form-upload" >
        <span id="upload-form" class="upload-form"></span>
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
          {{ form.csrf_token }}

        <div class="row card">
            <div class="logo">
                <h3 class="text-muted" text-align="center">LTE HO Fail Analysis</h3>
            </div>
            <BR></BR>
        <div>
            <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <th align="left">Start Date</th>
                <th align="left">End Date</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ form.StartDate(class='dtpick', value=StartDate)}}</td>
                <td>{{ form.EndDate(class='dtpick', value=EndDate)}}</td>

              </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <label class="text-muted">Site ID</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                  {{ form.site(class="form-control form-element") }}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sub" type="submit">Calculate</button>
                </div>

        <div>


    {% for key, value in result.items() %}
    <table border>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Cell Name:{{ key }} </b></td>

    </tr>

    {% for i,j in value[0].items() %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ i }}</td>
    <td align="center">{{ j| round(2, 'floor')  }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
          </table>
            <br />

     {% endfor %}

        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </TD>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
    {% endblock%}
````

7.After running the application, i am able to input selections through the form but when trying to get the result I am getting 'KEY ERROR'.Please let me know if i need to modify get_data_cell(self, cell_data, start_date, end_date) and the for loop being used in the template as well as in def lte_ho_fails() functions

Comment: It looks like you have copied a lot of information (much possibly unnecessary) and you have missed the key component... the full stack trace of the key error to actually debug your issue

Comment: thanks,specifically i want to know that from the input data how can i display the output table in flask.kindly let me know if you can view that pic of the output table in shared